# Django rest framework custom permissions not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

i have implemented django restframework custom permissions class for `staff-user` . but in my case `permission_class` is not working.

It would be great if any could figure out where i made mistake.

permissions.py :

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsStaff(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, obj):
        return obj.owner == request.user.is_stff()
```

views.py :

```
from .permissions import (IsStaff)

class CuboidListApiView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Cuboid
    queryset = Cuboid.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CuboidSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsStaff]
```

Comment: *The instance-level `has_object_permission(...)` method will only be called if the view-level `has_permission(...)` checks have already passed.* So, you need to implement the **`has_permission(...)`** too in the `IsStaff` class

Comment: Apart from that, since the `CuboidListApiView` class is a ***`ListAPIView`***, it doesn't make any sense to check the  ***object permission check***, which is usually called in [`RetrieveAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu  Thanks... it's worked and really very helpful too.